# Regarding real time updates using signal R

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to develop real time stock price updates application using Signal R.
For that purpose I have refer some tutorials based on SignalR
Now for that I will use yahoo or google apis to fetch live price and display it in my web app.
Problem is how my hub or my client side functions will know,that price has been changed,So it can take latest stock price from api and then I can broadcast to particular group

Comment: SignalR won't magically make 3rd party webservices become realtime.  But it would let you create your own realtime-ish service that acts as a proxy to a legacy service (like google or yahoo) that need to be polled.  There are quite a few steps involved in doing this though so you should probably break it down and ask one or more specific questions

Comment: Ok,now my problem is how can I call google or yahoo api service call.I mean how to detect that previous stock price has changed so now i have to make google or yahoo api call to get latest price.and thenafter getting updated price and display on my site.??

Comment: well that's unrelated to signalr but basically your server just needs to poll the google/yahoo service (subject to their terms of service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything regarding getting the API data realtime. That's how they've implemented it. If they support real time then it should be mentioned in their API. What you can do is, periodically call their API from your code behind and see whether there are any updates available. You can use SignalR to push the updates to client side. Implement server side and client side in your application so whenever an update available from your periodical checking, it will push the updates to client side.